# How to keep large graph in memory with PHP and C?

Tags: php, c, sockets, caching, data-structures

I need to make a web application which will, besides other stuff, do queries on large graph (data structure). I will just run Dijkstra or A* algorithm on graph, and return shortest path to the user as server response (probably JSON format). But the graph is very large and constructing it each time when user queries for shortest path from point A to point B is not very efficient. I need to find a way to keep graph in memory.

So, I am thinking about making a C program, which I will run once, it will construct graph and then open server socket and start listening on some port. Then in PHP I would connect to that program via socket, send points A and B and wait for response.

But I am not sure how good is this solution... And is there any other better and more elegant solution? There is no particular reason why I am proposing to make standalone program in C for constructing graph, it is just that I am more comfortable writing it in C than in PHP and also C is quite faster then PHP (as far as I know, which may not be true today).

Comment: Congratulations, you've discovered one of the many reasons people hate PHP.

Comment: Why not just write the whole thing in C then? I'm sure there's a lightweight HTTP/REST thing you can integrate. If you're dead-set on using PHP you can always [write your own extension](http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/).

Comment: I have tried writing php extension, simple create an array of integer and two functions to add elements and read array. Turns out PHP_MSHUTDOWN_FUNCTION is called when there is no requests, so even if I add 5 numbers to array, if I do not make another request in let's say 20 seconds, PHP_MSHUTDOWN_FUNCTION is called and thus my array deleted (since I need to free allocated memory)

Comment: Also this web application is very large, I am going to use Laravel Framework to make it. So I can't just write whole thing in C which would be tremendously hard and time consuming (and painful) xD

Comment: You know what's worse? If the graph is large enough to matter (a few million nodes), A* starts to really hurt. Use Arc Flags, and you don't even need to load most of the graph.

Answer (score 1):

> I am thinking about making a C program, which I will run once, it will
>   construct graph and then open server socket and start listening on
>   some port.

This approach is totally valid, but it increases the complexity of the path finding program and complexity of the deployment of system.

Actually you can program it in PHP and store the object or any intermediate result in a serialized format using `serialize()`. But this may not be CPU efficient if your object is very large.

The third method other than using a listening application or PHP code could be a compiled PHP extension (in C/C++), this is way more CPU and memory efficient than in PHP codes. In the mean time, you can build your own search tree or index in static files for your system. However, the objects are still not persistent.

And at last, you can always build a listening service using PHP instead of C at anytime, using a socket approach http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php . It can still persist object and the program session will not end.

You should be able to make your own choice according to the nature(memory, CPU and logic complexity) of your application.